# Initialize Data Account owned by custom program in web3.js

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

I want to create Data Account to store `Vec<Pubkey>` and make it writable and readable by my custom program. But it's a little hard for me to make PDA by cpi inside the program cause Pubkey length may be various depending on user parameters. So we can't set MAX_LENGTH because it will take unnecessary rent fee from users. Just want to take as enough as Pubkey length user inputs.

What I exactly thought is to create Data Account in prior instruction and then read&write it in custom program.

https://solscan.io/tx/2epTYVZpyXHpL7x13hdPs6eVohoTJse9FAo4GoTBsuuPEV2fVnMyJ3kd6Mtix8uRMnDUvQeQGHGRRcs8Tff32B5s

This tx creates the Data Account in instruction#3 and probably it's modified by next instruction.

***This was my approach***

I created account in web3.js. we can set the space.

```
  const dataAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  // Calculate the size of the account to be created
  const dataSize = 8 + 32 * pubkeyCount;  

  const createTicketsDataInstruction = anchor.web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: creatorKeypair.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: dataAccount.publicKey,
    lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(dataSize),
    space: dataSize,
    programId: program.programId,
  });
```

Then I tried to access data account inside the program.

```
// dataAccount Struct
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct DataAccount {
    pub bump: u8,
    pub accounts: Vec<Pubkey>,
}

// in Ctx
    #[account(mut)]
    pub data_account: Box<Account<'info, DataAccount>>,
```

As a result, I got this error.

```
AnchorError caused by account: data_account. Error Code: AccountDiscriminatorMismatch. Error Number: 3002. Error Message: 8 byte discriminator did not match what was expected.
```

Can someone help me with Data Account in Solana please? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create data account in web3.js and read&write from custom program?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/11663/how-to-create-data-account-in-web3-js-and-readwrite-from-custom-program)